# Phantom device showing on Google Play

Tags: google-play-store, google-account

I was going to install an app to my device from Google Play on my desktop, when I noticed a "**No carrier Samsung GT-N7000**" in my device list:

[image: Samsung GT-N7000?]

*(the Nexus 7 is mine)*

Apparently this device is the original Galaxy Note<sup>[[1]](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_note_n7000-4135.php)</sup>. I've never even seen one of these devices, and there shouldn't be one registered on my account. It doesn't show on Android Device Manager.

Is someone else on my Play Store account, downloading apps/media on my credit card? I use 2FA, so I'm worried about how that could have happened. Is there anything I can do to find out more about this device?

Comment: It's a long shot but, have you ever installed custom firmware? If a ROM had an edited build.prop it **could** happen like this, but it's highly unlikely that they'd put in the original Note details in there. Since this is potentially a fraud situation I would contact Google asap about this, and keep a paper trail in place in the worst case scenario where transactions are initiated on your account you want to flag it ASAP to expedite any dispute resolution that may occur.

Comment: @RossC Yeah, I've run Paranoid Android and Cyanogenmod in the past, and I'm currently running the Android L Developer Preview on my tablet. I have contacted Google (though I'm not sure I've done it the right way, they seem intent on not dissuading users from contacting them)

Comment: I have a few devices showing that I don't actually own due to ROMs and my own messing with `build.prop` as well as certain Market Enabler type applications. Plants Vs Zombies 2 not compatible with Google Play Edition S4 ROMs etc, being the kind of thing that prompted messing with the settings. My keyboard has me registered as having 12 devices, six are real and six are the same device that was messed with. Very unlikely you'd get a Note 1 in there though. Unless something like the market enabler use it as a good default device to get compatibility with apps?

Comment: Are you using Android emulator on PC, e.g. BlueStacks? Recently I also observed this (Samsung device too) on my account after using BlueStacks and connect it to my Google account. However, I'm still not sure.

Comment: @AndrewT. Ah, that's it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sure that you never login to any Android physical devices recently, then there's a possibility that you're using Android emulator with Google Play services (e.g. BlueStacks), and login your Google account on it.

Based from observation (this question, self-testing, and [another source](http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-note-3/477580-bluestacks-pc-based-samsung-galaxy-note-3-have-i-been-hacked.html)), BlueStacks tends to emulate Samsung devices. As explained [by jpr on AndroidCentral forum](http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-note-3/477580-bluestacks-pc-based-samsung-galaxy-note-3-have-i-been-hacked.html#post4161268),

> Well, BlueStacks has to show as some type of device if you connect to Google Play to download apps, or you wouldn't be able to download apps from it. Which device it shows as can vary. It historically has been some type of Samsung device, usually a Galaxy, and usually is a T-Mobile version, but of course they could have randomized the carrier now or switched to AT&T to avoid easy detection.

<sup>(minor copyedited)</sup>