# Unknown device on Play Store

Tags: google-play-store, google-account

Something very strange happened, I was trying to install the Steam app and my LG device disappeared, a different device I never seen took it's place: **Telstra Samsung SM-G900F**. The first device is my tablet, but the second one is completely alien - Telstra is Australian and I'm in Brazil.

Has anyone seen something like this, how can I make my phone appear back in the list?

[image: unknown device]

Comment: Could be a caching issue.  Try logging in from a different browser or a private browsing session and tell us if you still see it.

Comment: no, same issue on private browsing .-.

Comment: Are you using BlueStacks or any Android emulator? (similar issue:  [Phantom device showing on Google Play](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/81368/))

Comment: It's strange that the date is unknown of that device. It's a Galaxy S5. Did you get any mails that you signed in on a new device?

Comment: When you select that device in Android device manager, can you get a location?

Comment: Did you change your `build.prop` file recently? You, or a root application, may have changed your device's "identity" for compatibility reasons (eg. installing incompatible apps, or Xposed framework)